# SUDZ generating errored code from my working WSDL

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, sudzc

I am attempting to generate my SOAP WSDL to obj-c using sudzc.  It will not compile because it is producing a generated class LenType, which attempts to bring in "string.h".  This is problematic...

/*
    LenType.h
    The interface definition of properties and methods for the LenType object.
    Generated by SudzC.com
*/

```
#import "Soap.h"

#import "string.h"
@class string;


@interface LenType : string              <<<<====  Error
{

}
+ (LenType*) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node;
- (id) initWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node;
- (NSMutableString*) serialize;
- (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSString*) nodeName;
- (NSMutableString*) serializeAttributes;
- (NSMutableString*) serializeElements;

@end
```

The error is "Expected Identifier" on the @interface line.

I see some problems here, because it appears to be attempting to use STL string as a super to this class, and in none of the other examples have I seen it build from an WSDL this way.  Any ideas?

Thanks.